# No member named 'frame' in struct CGRect

Tags: frame, cgrect

I get the error "No member named 'frame' in struct CGRect".

```
    UITouch *touch = [[event2 allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint touchlocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
if ( CGRectContainsPoint( enemy.frame, touchlocation ) ) {
    MedalGo = 0;
    // inside imgView
} else {
    // outside imgView Now we will found out is it within proximityImgViewRect
    CGRect proximityImgViewRect = CGRectMake( enemy.frame.origin.x-25,enemy.frame.origin.y - 25, enemy.frame.size.width+50,enemy.frame.size.height+50);
    if ( CGRectContainsPoint( proximityImgViewRect.frame, touchlocation ) ) {
        // inside proximityImgViewRect
        MedalGo = 1;

    } else {
        //outside proximityImgViewRect
        MedalGo = 0;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A CGRect is the frame.

```
 if ( CGRectContainsPoint( proximityImgViewRect.frame, touchlocation ) )
```

no

```
 if ( CGRectContainsPoint( proximityImgViewRect, touchlocation ) )
```

yes